# Numpy mean produces a wrong output when computing the mean of the noise

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, mean, noise

I am struggling to understand why np.mean fails when trying to estimate the mean value of a noisy signal. I thought about floating point errors but don't think that's the case.

Some background: I'm trying to estimate the noise standard deviation and the mean of the noise in a signal (image of a sharp edge).

First, let's generate a noisy image of an edge:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
```

Let's define a function that describes the edge

```
esf_p = lambda x, sigma, mu, I1, I0: I0  + (0.5)*(I1 - I0)*(1 + special.erf((x-mu)/(np.sqrt(2)*sigma)))
```

And now let's turn it into an image

```
x = np.mgrid[0:100,0:100][1]
im = esf_p(x, 0.62, 50 ,100, 0)
```

The output image looks like this

[image: Image with no noise]

Now let's add some noise to it

```
noisefunc = np.random.normal(loc = 0,  scale = esf_p(x, 0.62, 50, 10,  10))
im_noise = im + noisefunc
```

[image: Noisy image]

The problem I'm having is computing the mean of the noise. First we need to estimate the noise:

```
noise_est = im_noise - np.mean(im_noise, axis=0)
noise_mean_estimate = np.mean(noise_est, axis=0)
```

We can see that the the estimated noise is really close to the the noise function we added to the image if we pot a random row of pixels from the image (let's do the last row of pixels).

```
plt.plot(noise_est[-1], label = 'estimated')
plt.plot(noisefunc[-1], label= 'original noise')
plt.legend()
```

Comparing the estimated noise with the ground truth noise function:
[image: Comparing the estimated noise with the ground truth noise function]

We can see that the estimated noise is pretty close to the ground truth noise function.

Now, here is where it gets weird. I want to compute the mean of the noise estimate. However, the values I get are absurd.

```
noise_mean = np.mean(noise_est, axis=0)
plt.plot(np.sqrt(100)*noise_mean, label = 'mean of noise from noise estimate')
plt.legend()
```

Mean of the estimated noise function:
[image: Mean of the estimated noise function]

Obviously the mean should be a lot higher (we used a standard deviation of 10).

The factor of square root of 100 just reflects the fact that we have averaged over a 100 rows in the image and we want the mean of the noise, not the noise of the mean.

What's even more bizarre is that if we get rid of the last row of pixels in our estimate of the noise mean the results change dramatically (by 13 orders of magnitude).

```
noise_mean = np.mean(noise_est[:-1, :], axis=0)
plt.plot(np.sqrt(99)*noise_mean, label = 'mean of noise from noise estimate')
plt.legend()
```

Mean of the estimated noise function without the last row:
[image: Mean of the estimated noise function without the last row]

Now, the estimated mean looks a lot better, however it is still 1 order of magnitude lower than the ground truth.

Oddly enough, this issue does not pop up when estimating the mean of the ground truth noise function:

```
plt.plot(np.sqrt(100)*np.mean(noisefunc, axis=0), label = 'mean of ground truth noise')
plt.plot(noisefunc[-1], label = 'noise in last row of pixels')
plt.legend()
```

Comparing the mean of the ground truth noise with the last row of pixels in ground truth noise function:
[image: Comparing the mean of the ground truth noise with the last row of pixels in ground truth noise function]

So we can see that the square root of n term just scales up the estimated noise value.

Let's try to compute the standard deviation as a function of increasing rows:

test_std = np.zeros(100)

```
   for i in range(100):
        test_std[i] = np.sqrt(i)*np.std(np.mean(noise_est[:i+1, :], axis=0), axis=0)
   plt.plot(test_std, label = 'std of estimated noise mean')
   plt.legend()
```

Standard deviation of the estimated noise mean as a function of increasing rows:
[image: Standard deviation of the estimated noise mean as a function of increasing rows]

We can see that it tries to go up to 10 for a low number of rows and then drops massively (with the full 100 rows going down to something like 1e-13). So it get's less and less accurate as more rows are averaged over (one would expect the opposite)

If we investigate the behavior of the mean of the ground truth noise function as a function of increasing rows we see that mean remains constant:

```
test_std = np.zeros(100)
for i in range(100):
    test_std[i] = np.sqrt(i)*np.std(np.mean(noisefunc[:i+1, :], axis=0), axis=0)
plt.plot(test_std, label = 'std of ground truth noise function')
plt.legend()
```

Standard deviation of the mean of the ground truth noise function with respect to increasing rows:
[image: Standard deviation of the mean of the ground truth noise function with respect to increasing rows]

So what could be happening with np.mean()? Why is it outputting such a drastic change in the mean of the noise estimate just by taking away the last row? And why would it behave well for the ground truth but completely mess up the estimated noise? They seem incredibly close as we saw.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong so any comments/ suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you do `im_noise - np.mean(im_noise, axis=0)` you perform a zero mean normalization on each column, so of course after that the mean on each column will be... zero. There is nothing wrong with `np.mean()` here.

Comment: And if after the zero mean normalization you remove one row, then it is no more zero centered and your "noise" will increase.

Comment: To expand on @obchardon's comment: when you do `noise_est = im_noise - np.mean(im_noise, axis=0)`, the mean of each column of `noise_est` would be *zero* if you were computing with infinite precision.  With 64 bit floating point, the means of the columns will be very small, but not *exactly* zero.  And for the columns on the right, where `im` is 100, the errors will be larger, because of the additional loss of precision that occurs when subtracting numbers that are approximately equal.  That explains the graph labeled `'mean of noise from noise estimate'`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the addition. So, if we suppose that your edge are perfectly vertical and uniform, then `np.std(noise_est)` will give you the standard deviation of the noise.